# High CPU using while dragging with brush tool in photoshop cc

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This problem is happening while i am using my brush tool in photoshop cc. So you will be clear, please see the video i captured on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_f1cTjjPTc&feature=youtu.be Please let me know if there any solution you can have.

### *My System Info:*

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [High CPU using while dragging with brush tool in photoshop cc](http://superuser.com/questions/882450/high-cpu-using-while-dragging-with-brush-tool-in-photoshop-cc)

Answer (score 0):

Do you  have GPU acceleration enabled (Edit > Preferences > Performance > Advanced Settings)?  Enabling that (if your computer supports it) will make Photoshop use your graphics card (GPU) instead of the CPU for some intensive tool operations.

Comment: Its Enabled and Drawing Mode Is Advanced. But The Problem is happening